# How to show multiple HTML contents in a single page in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

Suppose I'm opening email details in a ASP.Net .aspx page div control. The problem is when I'm opening an email details containing html tag the page is showing messed up. Only the inner html contents are showing on the page. Is there any way I could solve this problem.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <body>
            <form >
    <!-- Outer HTML contents... -->

         <div id="dvViewMailReadOnly" style="overflow:auto; width:100%;height:auto;">
         <html>
            <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            </head>
            <body>
            <img src="http://click.email.skype...>
            </body>
        </html>
            </div>
            </form>
            </body>
           </html>
```

The email contents are showing on dvViewMailReadOnly dynamically.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the HTML that is causing this issue? I'm not sure I understand the problem, and without any code, I don't think it will be possible to help you.

Comment: I have edited my questain with HTML @Lars Kristensen

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure I understand the problem. Yes, the HTML is invalid, as there *must only be **one*** `<html>` element (and consequently also only one `<head>` and `<body>` element).

If you are allowed to modify your form, then you could simply do this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <form >
            <!-- Outer HTML contents... -->
            <div id="dvViewMailReadOnly" style="overflow:auto; width:100%;height:auto;">
                <img src="http://click.email.skype...">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: got your point but itz impossible to filter all HTML tags from inner HTML contents which is generating dynamically.Anyway thanks for your effort @Lars Kristensen

Comment: You haven't explained exactly how the content is being dynamically generated. I'm guessing there's some sort of template for this, which contains the `<html>` tags. If this is the case, can you alter the template? If this is not the case, can you elaborate on how it is being dynamically generated?

Comment: I'm showing my outlook mail details on "dvViewMailReadOnly" from my ASP.Net application. There are few emails which contains details like a whole HTML page as mentioned above in my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace < by &lt; and > by &gt;
```